# Ajax.ActionLink as a Img - Getting code written instead of a img link

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, hyperlink

I am trying to insert a img to use as a Ajax.ActionLink.

This is the code:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("[replacethis]", "_Edit", "Account", new { id = "<#= UserId#>" }, new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "subForm", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "GET" }).ToHtmlString().Replace("[replacethis]", "<img src=\"" + Url.Content("../../Scripts/ribbonfiles/ribbon/images/cadUsers.png") + "\" />"));
```

The problem is that I get all the code printed instead of get a img as a link.

Am I missing something?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could not find a solution for that, so I am creating a img link and calling a js function to do whatever I want.

Best I could do.

Comment: Yeah, could´nt find a way either! I have just abandoned and I am using a img link too. Thanks